# How to generate and display TCPDF pdf on a page that has already loaded?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF using TCPDF on the fly and display it in the browser.

I have already...

- Output the PDF as a download
- Output the PDF inline without any HTML. (using `$pdf->Output('example_007.pdf', 'I');`

**What I want to do is...**

- Output the PDF inline with HTML already printed, without cleaning out that HTML.

Naturally I ran into the `TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file` issue. I managed to get rid of this error using the ob functions, such as `ob_start`, or `ob_flush`; however, this clears my existing HTML.

I've tried outputting the PDF on a PHP file that was called through AJAX (pure JavaScript); however, I have not had any luck with that end. Nothing ever appeared.

**So how would you display a PDF in the browser while content is already outputted?**

I am more or less looking for something like following:

[image]

I am currently doing this with a test page, here is my code: ... Most of it is from the TCPDF's examples.

```
//The following PHP block was tried but also failed as it wiped existing HTML
<?php
    ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Before PDF</h1>
        <?php
            error_Reporting(E_ALL);

            date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

            // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
            require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/my-site/TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php";

            //ob_start() Tried this at some point... Didn't work

            // create new PDF document
            $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

            // set document information
            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
            $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
            $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
            $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

            // set default header data
            $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
            $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

            // set header and footer fonts
            $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

            // set default monospaced font
            $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

            // set margins
            $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
            $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
            $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

            // set auto page breaks
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

            // set image scale factor
            $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

            // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
            if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
                require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
                $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
            }

            // ---------------------------------------------------------

            // set default font subsetting mode
            $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

            // Set font
            // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
            // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
            // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
            $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

            // Add a page
            // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
            $pdf->AddPage();

            // set text shadow effect
            $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

            // Set some content to print
            $html = "
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            ";

            // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

            // ---------------------------------------------------------

            // Close and output PDF document
            // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.

            //ob_clean(); Various posts suggested various combinations of these methods
            //ob_flush();
            $pdf->Output('example_007.pdf', 'I');
            //ob_end_flush();
            //ob_end_clean();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same technique you used to display it inline you could try to load the PDF file using an Iframe:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>some content</p>
        <iframe src="/path/to/your/pdf/script.php"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did a lot of messing using the HTML object element, though I can try using the Iframe. It'll need some time to mess around with it.

Comment: @gp_sflover this was more of an answer in shape of a question than a request for clarification. But thanks for the clarification

Comment: +1 and an imaginary cake. I tried using object element; however, I never though of putting the PDF code inside another file and then directing the src /data attribute to that file. That method appears to be working.

Comment: it's normally the simplest solutions that do it :)

Comment: @ClaudioPinto the initial format (without code) seemed only a request for the OP. Anyway you should always avoid to use question marks inside answers :-).

Comment: @ClaudioPinto I've run into another issue... Is there a way to have the pdf script declare a php function, and then have the function output the pdf into the src attribute? When I tried this I got a bunch of unreadable characters... If not then I'll have to make a question when I start optimizing the website.

Comment: Not of my knowledge. But you sure can have a PDF file with a link to a php page that generates another PDF.